# 'VBoxManage guestcontrol' to run shell script on guest

Tags: virtualbox

I have VirtualBox VM that runs a server that can be accessed via localhost and forwarded ports.
I need to run some shells scripts and implement some business logic based on the results.

I tried following command as example:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol <UUID> exec --image /bin/sh --username <su username> --password <su password> --wait-exit --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- "[ -d /<server_folder>/ ] && echo "OK" || echo "Server is not installed""
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
/bin/sh: [ -d <server_folder> ] && echo : No such file or directory
```

What is wrong with the syntax above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that `VBoxManage.exe` is in your path!

Secondly you have to be carefull with your quotations. You used:

```
"[ -d /<server_folder>/ ] && echo "OK" || echo "Server is not installed""
```

you have to use singel quotaions for the outermost quotation:

```
'[ -d /<server_folder>/ ] && echo "OK" || echo "Server is not installed"'
```

Finally you have to add a `-c` in front of your arguments (to call `/bin/sh -c '...'`).

The complete command:

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol <UUID> exec --image /bin/sh --username <su username> --password <su password> --wait-exit --wait-stdout --wait-stderr -- -c '[ -d /<server_folder>/ ] && echo "OK" || echo "Server is not installed"'
```